# drawing rectangle in openCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to draw rectangle using mouse as input with Opencv in c++. I want to draw a rectangle by dragging and dropping.

How can I draw clean unfilled rectangle? where I can see drawing an actual rectangle. Like we do in Paint

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat img;
Point ptOld;
void on_mouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void*);


 int main(void)
 {
     img = imread("lenna.bmp");

     if (img.empty()) {
         cerr << "Image load failed" << endl;
         return -1;
     }

     namedWindow("img");
     setMouseCallback("img", on_mouse);
     imshow("img", img);
     waitKey(0);

     return 0;
 }

 void on_mouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void*)
 {
     switch (event) {
     case EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
         ptOld = Point(x, y);
         break;

     case EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
         ptOld = Point(x, y);
         break;

     case EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
         if (flags & EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON) {
             rectangle(img, ptOld, Point(x,y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
             imshow("img", img);
             ptOld = Point(x, y);

         }
         break;

     default:
         break;
         
     }
 }
```

[lenna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNpAe.jpg)

can anyone tell me why is that happening? any solution on it??

I want this result.

[example]https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvXMP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should operate on two images. One is used to draw currently selected rectangle by mouse move event. When button-up event occures this image is entry point of next rectangle drawing operation, and should be stored in second image.

```
Mat tempImg, imgWithRects;
Point ptOld;
void on_mouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void*);

int main(void) {
    imgWithRects = imread("lenna.bmp"); 
    if (imgWithRects.empty()) {
         cerr << "Image load failed" << endl;
         return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("img");
    setMouseCallback("img", on_mouse);
    imshow("img", imgWithRects);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

void on_mouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void*)
{
 switch (event) {
 case EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
     ptOld = Point(x, y);
     break;
 case EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
     ptOld = Point(x, y);
     if (!tempImg.empty())
         imgWithRects = tempImg.clone();
     break;
 case EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
     if (flags & EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON) {
         tempImg = imgWithRects.clone();
         rectangle(tempImg, ptOld, Point(x,y), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
         imshow("img", tempImg);
     }
     break;
 default:
     break;   
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved the problem! I am very happy because of you. I wish you all the best.